# Synchronizing multiple threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a multi-threaded environment in .NET that needs to communicate to a library. The library has some limitations and therefore cannot work correctly with multi-threaded environments. I need a way to solve this issue by making middle layer that the multi-threaded environment communicates with and then calls the library. I made a solution that solved the problem but I am not convinced that it is the best one. I created an asynchronous thread that has a run method. The run method is in infinite loop that checks what is the current task (a parameter that I set) and executes the corresponding method.

As I said, I am not convinced at all with this solution but it does the job correctly. So please inform me if there is a better one to solve it (especially if it is related to C#).

Just as a side note, the limitation isn't due to multiple threads that are working at the same time and causing data corruption. I need the exact same thread to do everything (depends on thread id).

Comment: Your approach sounds fine. The thread with the infinite loop should sleep when there is no pending task. Does your implementation do that? If not, post some code so we can help you with this.

Comment: You'll probably want to use a [BlockingCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) wrapping a [ConcurrentQueue<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx).

Comment: You could also implement a custom [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx) that schedules all tasks on the same thread.

Comment: Thanks @dtb for the response. Yes, I am using a sleep() when there are no pending tasks and have locks where there might be a multi-threaded access to a resource. It works well and I didn't have any problems with it. I was just not sure if it is correct way to go with. About the TaskScheduler, I need the output of the methods as well. That's my biggest problem. At my solution, I made a parameter called 'result' that is always the output. So I check when the task status is COMPLETED and then I get the result. The thread wait until the status is completed

Comment: Sleep() is not a good idea, because you want the thread to wake up as soon as there is a new task, not wake up every x seconds to check if there is one. I'd definitely recommend implementing a TaskScheduler  that schedules all tasks on the same thread. You can schedule a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) (no result) or a  [Task<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) (result of type T). Both classes support waiting for the task to complete or asynchronously invoking a callback upon completion.

Comment: You can use a [BlockingCollection<Task>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) wrapping a [ConcurrentQueue<Task>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) to implement the scheduler. The Task, Task<T> and TaskScheduler classes are part of the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx).

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks a lot for the help. Could you please put it as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx).

I recommend you implement a custom [TaskScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx) that schedules all tasks on the same thread. You can use the scheduler to schedule a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) (no result value) or a [Task<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx) (result of type T).

You can use a [BlockingCollection<Task>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) wrapping a [ConcurrentQueue<Task>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx) to implement the scheduler.

For example, assuming that your library exposes a function *MakeCoffee*, you could create a  class *CoffeeMachine* that provides a matching wrapper method and schedules the task of calling the library on the custom scheduler:

```
public class CoffeeMachine
{
    private readonly TaskScheduler scheduler;

    public CoffeeMachine()
    {
        this.scheduler = new SingleThreadTaskScheduler();
    }

    public Task<Coffee> MakeCoffeeAsync()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew<Coffee>(
            this.MakeCoffee,
            CancellationToken.None,
            TaskCreationOptions.None,
            this.scheduler);
    }

    private Coffee MakeCoffee()
    {
        // this method will always execute on the same thread
    }
}
```

*Usage:*

```
CoffeeMachine machine = new CoffeeMachine();

Task<Coffee> task = machine.MakeCoffeeAsync();   // start task

task.Wait();                                     // wait for task to complete
Drink(task.Result);                              // use result
```